# Bootstrap-5 fixed-top navbar with internal links doesn't scroll right

Tags: bootstrap-5, href

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 5's `navbar` with `fixed-top`, where all the nav-items are references to anchors on the page. When I click on links that are below the current position, it goes to the right place, but if I click, say, "Link 1" when I'm looking at section 3, section 1 ends up with the top bit buried under the navbar. Here is some code slightly modified from this [CopyCat.dev example](https://www.copycat.dev/blog/bootstrap-navbar/)

I've seen answers here and elsewhere saying to put a `margin-top` on the `body`, on the `<main>` or on the individual sections. I've tried all those. I've also tried using `padding-top` instead.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target=".navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-info fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Navbar title -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap-Navbar</a>
    
                <!-- Navbar mobile Hamburger -->
                <button
                    class="navbar-toggler"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    
                <!-- Navbar Items -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-1">Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-2">Link 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-3">Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-4">Link 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    
        <main class="pt-5">
            <section
            id="section-1"
            class="vh-100 text-center fs-2 text-white bg-danger"
            >
            Section 1
            </section>
            <section
            id="section-2"
            class="vh-100 text-center fs-2 text-white bg-warning"
            >
            Section 2
            </section>
            <section
            id="section-3"
            class="vh-100 text-center p-5 fs-2 text-white bg-success"
            >
            Section 3
            </section>
            <section
            id="section-4"
            class="vh-100 text-center p-5 fs-2 text-white bg-info"
            >
            Section 4
            </section>
        </main>
        <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just discovered adding `style="margin-top: -50px; padding-top: 50px; background-clip: content-box;"` to each `section` seems to help. I need to explore a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the css file:

```
body {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
section {
  padding-top: 56px;
  margin-top: -56px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
main {
  padding-top: 56px;
}
```

That seems to have taken care of it, at least on Chrome and Firefox.